# problem about linear dependence in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show only using result about system of homogeneous linear equation (i mean **only using calculus technique and not theorems about vectorial spaces**) that 4 vectors are linear dependent using 3 generators? my teacher said in this case i have 3 equation with 4 variables but i can't see this . Why 4 variables and not 3 (generators)?

Comment: You might want to state the "result about a system of homogeneous linear equations" to make it more clear.

Comment: only using linear combinations and calculus , no theorems about vectorial spaces

Comment: Yes add that result  to your question.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not understanding "4 vectors are linear dependent using 3 generators"

Comment: there are 3 vector that generate my entire space and 4 vectors. and i have to show that these 4 vector are linear depent

Comment: If we assume that the three vectors that generate the space and a vector $u\in V$ are linealy independent the matrix $M=(v_1|v_2|v_3|u)$ would have rank $4$ but $M\in \operatorname{M}(3\times 4,\mathbb K)$ so...

Comment: so the max rank would be 3 and that is impossible right?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473853/prove-that-n1-vectors-in-mathbbrn-cannot-be-linearly-independent).

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know about rhe existence of this question . Anyway thanks for having shared this with me there are a lot of interesting proofs